# How to declare a record such that one of its fields is a function

Tags: z3

I'm very new to Z3, so sorry for asking something silly.

I'm trying to define a record such that some of its fields are functions. I tried this:

(declare-datatypes (DOM RAN) ((PFun (mk-pfun (dom (DOM) Bool) (law (DOM) RAN)))))

with the intention that dom and ran are two fields whose type is a function (dom a function from DOM to Bool, and law a function from DOM to RAN). I tried also by enclosing the function type in parenthesis:

(declare-datatypes (DOM RAN) ((PFun (mk-pfun (dom ((DOM) Bool)) (law ((DOM) RAN))))))

bun none of these work.

I searched the tutorial but there are no examples of this.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

All the best,
  Maxi

Answer (score 1):

Z3 is based on first-order logic. So, functions cannot be arguments of datatype constructors or other functions. 
That being said, you can “simulate” high-order features using arrays.
You can write your datatype as

```
  (declare-datatypes (DOM RAN) ((PFun (mk-pfun (dom (Array DOM Bool)) 
                                               (law (Array DOM RAN))))))
```

Let `p` be a `PFun` and `d` a constant of sort `DOM`, then you write `(select (dom p) d)` to obtain `dom(p)(d)`, and `(select (law p) d)` to obtain `law(p)(d)`.